# Selenium error: element click intercepted:Other element would receive the click:

Tags: python, html, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use Selenium to click on "show more" under "about this show" on this URL:

[https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1024477910-hot-8-brass-band-at-the-howlin'-wolf?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event](https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1024477910-hot-8-brass-band-at-the-howlin%27-wolf?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event)

Here's my code:

```
#Get Event Info - expand 'read more'
    try:
        time.sleep(3)
        readMoreEvent = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xXGKBimvIBU_aEdJh3EF']").click();
        print("More Event Info Clicked")
    except (ElementNotVisibleException, NoSuchElementException, TimeoutException):
        pass
```

I'm getting an error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted:

.</div> is not clickable at point (477, 9). Other element would receive the click:
```

Here's a photo of the div I'm trying to click:

[image]

So, it seems like something is blocking the page-click.  How can I solve this issue?

Comment: did you run without option `headless` to see what you really have in browser? Maybe it displays some message (ie. cookie message) and it hides your link - you may have to first remove/close message. OR maybe it needs only to scroll to this element - so it will be visible in window.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I saw that there's a dialogue box that pops up which asks user to login. That could be interrupting the click.

A better approach is to:

1. Wait until the link is clickable
2. Capture the exception and use an alternative method to click on the link

This should work:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from time import sleep

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='D://chromedriver/100/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

url = "https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1024477910-hot-8-brass-band-at-the-howlin%27-wolf?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event"

driver.get(url)

try:
    showmore_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="xXGKBimvIBU_aEdJh3EF"]')))
    showmore_link.click()

except ElementClickInterceptedException:
    print("Trying to click on the button again")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", showmore_link)
```